# Same code, same library, but why my training runs slower in a new laptop compare to an old laptop

Tags: tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, hardware

Here is the background:

I do not know much about Deep learning, and I am not the one creates the code. I follow someone's procedure and test the AI. I try the same process on 3 different laptop. I thought a laptop with better hardware would increase the training speed but ends up this is not that case.

Base on the code, seems it was using Keras with tensorflow backend.

I did some research and try to speed up the process: like use GPU.But then I found out that both laptop the GPU load was in 0 to 1%. seems the GPU is not used on both laptop.

So I think, maybe the tensorflow didnt recognize the GPU, so I try to use tersorflow-gpu, install cuda and cudnn...

```
>>> from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
>>> print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
2021-08-18 17:17:00.307495: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2
2021-08-18 17:17:00.312631: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2021-08-18 17:17:00.364157: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1555] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070 computeCapability: 6.1
coreClock: 1.645GHz coreCount: 16 deviceMemorySize: 8.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 238.66GiB/s
2021-08-18 17:17:00.364352: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2021-08-18 17:17:00.397938: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2021-08-18 17:17:00.427946: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-08-18 17:17:00.435072: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-08-18 17:17:00.478467: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2021-08-18 17:17:00.495200: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2021-08-18 17:17:00.559633: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2021-08-18 17:17:00.560557: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1697] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-08-18 17:17:04.129809: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1096] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-08-18 17:17:04.129968: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1102]      0
2021-08-18 17:17:04.130734: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] 0:   N
2021-08-18 17:17:04.132802: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1241] Created TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0 with 6788 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 2340425778646607054
, name: "/device:GPU:0"
device_type: "GPU"
memory_limit: 7118530151
locality {
  bus_id: 1
  links {
  }
}
incarnation: 4718765836722936952
physical_device_desc: "device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1"
]
```

Even tensorflow-gpu seems recognize the GPU, Still not getting faster and the laptop without GPU and older CPU were actually faster.

The New laptop runs about 1 it/s, but the Old laptop runs in 9 it/s.I also have an even older laptop can runs in 5~6 it/s

Now to train 14 GB dataset it takes me estimate 30days with the old laptop, and the new laptop would takes maybe 45days.

The things bugging me is: with the same code and library, the next thing would affect the training speed isnt the hardware? Or there are something I misunderstood?

[image: Hardware Spec]

Comment: Did you make changes to the code as well to specify which part will run on GPU?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like a particular operation to run on a device of your choice instead of what's automatically selected for you, you can use with `tf.device` to create a device context, and all the operations within that context will run on the same designated device.

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)

# Place tensors on the CPU
with tf.device('/CPU:0'):
  a = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]])
  b = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0]])

# Run on the GPU
c = tf.matmul(a, b)
print(c)
```